# Should I guide the user in their account set up? Designing for web

Tags: website-design, web

So, I know that when designing for mobile dividing processes into steps makes the user feel not so overwhelmed by the amount of options/fields that are required. Does this hold for web development?

This is how the 'set up guide' looks right now:

1) User signs up normally
[image]

2) User chooses if they want to follow the guide 
[image]

3) User adds profile info. 
[image]

4) User adds opening hours
[image]

This would have one more step, but I think my point is shown. The user is required to add 'complex' information, and in order to have the user set it up at the start I think is better to walk them through than leaving them alone at the dashboard.

Should I keep the 'guided sign up' feature? Any tips on how to improve it? Should I leave the option for the user to choose whether or not to be guided?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, users on web also need help. It is good practice to make it an option,

First of all, I think you need to work with your copy (which you probably will see if you test your design).

As a user I have many questions:
 * What am I signing up for
 * What am I getting (value)
 * Etc.

I would test it with 2-5 users. Then I would come up with solutions to the issues found during the tests and run tests again.

Think aloud test is a great one for this type and I belive you would find alot of things you need to explain to a potential user.

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/why-you-only-need-to-test-with-5-users/

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/thinking-aloud-the-1-usability-tool/

Answer (score 0):

Helping the user with step by step guide is really useful. Also, reducing a step may help. You can move step 2 into the dashboard. Here is how:

When user will signup they will directly go to the Dashboard. A small modal will appear (where it fits best for the user in your application) and ask if the user needs a guided walk through or not. If they click on the guided setup button the guided setup will start. If they click on cancel the modal will be closed. But a button to open the modal for guided setup will stay in the corner or on top navigation if the user got stuck or need the guided setup later.

Here is a simple example. 
[image]

---

But test the solutions with your users to find out which method suits the best.